# JAVA Optimize char[] to String conversion

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

This is a solution to this [Hackerrank Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-binary-string)

```
String b = new String(in.nextLine());
char[] bCharArray = b.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
  if (b.substring(i, i + 3).matches("010")) {
    bCharArray[i + 2] = '1';
    b = new String(bCharArray);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Now in the for loop part, each time a new instance for the String b is created. Is there any better way to implement an optimized char[] to String conversion?

Comment: Wait ... you never thought about creating that String ***outside*** the loop? Isn't this the most obivous change?

Comment: no... that's useless... i need to save the changes to the string at every iteration

Comment: No you don't and the first answer told you the same.

Comment: no it doesn't @Tom. I just checked what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new String in each iteration, how about you work on the original char array and only when you've finished modifying the characters can you copy it into a string (if that's what you want).

Here is the alternative code:

```
String b = new String(in.nextLine());
char[] bCharArray = b.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
    if(bCharArray[i] == '0' && bCharArray[i+1] == '1' && bCharArray[i+2] == '0')
   {
     bCharArray[i+2] = '1';
   }
}
```

Comment: this is good. but I think it takes more time as there are a lot of comparisions in each iteration. Isn't it ?

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj Do you think creating a substring and compiling a regex comes for free?

Comment: ohh... sorry didn't think of it ;)

Comment: There are exactly three comparisons in each iteration in my code which is equivalent to the number of comparisons in yours (those that are done when you call the methods substring() and matches()). So, no, it doesn't take any more time. In fact, it takes less since it doesn't allocate additional strings in each iteration.